# Loop mixed models and tukey comparison

Tags: r, mixed-models, tukey

I would like to loop a mixed model and Tukey test.
All I want to do is to repeat the fitting and the comparison for 3 columns (each one containing a response) and for 4 subgroups (total = 12).

A similar dataframe is available here: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bwrsa11LAnrgTXMzWk1fYXR1MHM.  The 3 resposes are the columns "RESP_1","RESP_2" and "RESP_3", the subgroups are the variables of column "layer".

I obtain the model and the adjustament for a single response and unique layer by:

```
#mixed model    
Mlm_RESP_1 <-lme(RESP_1~clay+till, random=~1|strata/point, data=loop_lm_tukey)

#tukey
ls_RSP_1 <- lsmeans(Mlm_RESP_1,pairwise~till,adjust="tukey")
ls_RSP_1$contrasts
cld(ls_RSP_1)
```

Then, I try to loop the model for each column by:

```
#loop model    
mlm_RESP <- lapply(c("RESP_1", "RESP_2","RESP_3"), function(k) {
      lme(eval(substitute(j ~ clay+till, list(j = as.name(k)))), random = ~1|strata/point, data = loop_lm_tukey)})
```

From now, I am not able to loop the Tukey comparison using lsmeans package because `lapply` returns a list and this package can't handle this kind of class.

Furthermore, how can I loop this for every layer?

Any help to do loop of Tukey's comparison would be much appreciated.

Comment: You should be able to `lapply()` tukey over the `mlm_RESP` list.

Comment: Just run lsmeans on each member of the list.

Comment: `lsmeans` can't handle a member of a list. However I would like to learn how to do a loop (I have other 3 data frames to apply this action).

Comment: On each model in the list.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
mlm_RESP <- lapply(c("RESP_1", "RESP_2","RESP_3"), function(k) { 
  df=cbind(resp=loop_lm_tukey[,k],loop_lm_tukey[,-c(1:3)])
  lme(resp~clay+till, random = ~1|strata/point, data = df)})

res1=lapply(mlm_RESP,function(rm)lsmeans(rm,pairwise~till,adjust="tukey"))
```

or:

```
res2=list()
for (i in 1:3) res2[[i]]=lsmeans(mlm_RESP[[i]],pairwise~till,adjust="tukey")
```

The results is the same.

Comment: running the code, it returns an error: `Error in as.name(k) : object 'k' not found
Error in ref.grid(object = list(modelStruct = list(reStruct = list(point = 8.82313412464084,  : 
  Perhaps a 'data' or 'params' argument is needed`